# how to prevent saving data in save_model in admin.py?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to override django UserAdmin save_model method in `admin.py`

In some case I want to ignore saving data. Am I missing something in else section.
here is my code:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.owner = request.user.id

    if request.POST.get('code') != '41798':
        super(ProductAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    else :
        self.message_user(request, "ignore save", messages.ERROR)
        .... ???
```

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add `return` in the save_model

```
return super(ProductAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: With your suggestion does not save existing data ‌?

Answer (score 0):

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.owner = request.user.id

    if request.POST.get('code') != '41798':
        super(ProductAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
    else :
        self.message_user(request, "ignore save", messages.ERROR)
        return None
```

That should work.